# Shell/Bash script telnet testing a multicast address

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to create a shell/bash script to telnet test to a multicast address. I currently have the following:

```
telnet <ip_address> <port_number>
```

However, this hangs:

```
<server_name>% ./telnet_test.sh
Trying <ip_address>...
Connected to <ip_address>.
Escape character is '^]'.
//Hangs here for a few seconds...
Connection to <ip_address> closed by foreign host.
```

How can I test the multicast address and return immediately if successful so that I do not have to wait until the connection is closed by the foreign host.

I will need to test multiple addresses in the same script.

EDIT:

I should have mentioned that I am an on a bank network with tightly controlled firewalls and I cannot have netcat installed.

The purpose of this test is just to see if I can connection to that route from my current host.

Comment: first type the escape character ^[   then type the exit, quit, or bye to close telnet.

Comment: check mcast addresses for what? It does not make any sense to test mcast which is based on UDP with telnet, which is a TCP program. Also if a host sees mcast messages, then it is not necessary to reply to them so you can prove nothing really.

Comment: What do you mean with `testing the multicast address`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `netcat` instead.
`-z` - scan for listening daemons.
`-w 3` - timeout after 3 seconds

```
#!/bin/bash

host_list="www.google.com www.stackoverflow.com"
port=80

for host in $host_list; do
    nc -z -w 3 $host $port > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
        printf "%s%s%s\n" " [$host:" "UP" "]"
    else
        printf "%s%s%s\n" " [$host:" "DOWN" "]"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `expect` installed you can use it to control your `telnet`:

```
#!/usr/bin/except
spawn telnet <ip address> <port number>
set timeout 10
expect "Connected to"
send "exit\r"
```

Check `man expect` and [some other article](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/144080-expect-script-automate-telnet-session.html) for more info.